# Number of cuts in a 30min video file

Tags: video, slice

I have a video that is 30min long (encoded mp4:h264) and I need to count the numbers of cuts in the movie. It should include cuts as well as cross-fades.

So something quite similar to i-Frame detection....

I have available Linux with ffmpeg / libav as well as a Windows with Adobe Premiere.

Any clues? Or other software?

Comment: It would be a good idea to ask on [Doom9](http://forum.doom9.org/)

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing you'd do with a clicker (press a button every time an event of interest appears) manually, as if you only have 1 video and only need to do this once a programmatic solution may be overkill.

Comment: The crossfades won't be easy to get with any program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out, obtaining good accuracy with an automatic solution is difficult. Crossfades, zooms, pans, etc... all make it difficult for an automatic tool to conclude if consecutive frames belong to the same scene or not.

That being said, I would try to use the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library to analyze differences between consecutive frames and try to determine, using some empirical threshold, if they are similar enough to be considered from the same scene (choose the interval of frames, not necessarily every frame).

It's easy to extract frames from a video using the [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) class.

Once frames are extracted you can use various methods to try to decide if two frames are related.

A few ideas:

1. Use the [Lucas-Kanade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method) method to [find the optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) between frames and conclude if the difference indeed results from motion of objects in the frames, or if it's completely different scenes.
2. Use a [features detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html) algorithm ([SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform), [SURF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF), etc) to characterize the frame and [compare it](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html) to other frames. See also discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146542/opencv-surf-how-to-generate-a-image-hash-fingerprint-signature-out-of-the).

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic computer vision problem. The search term is 'video scene segmentation', 'video scene extraction', 'automated video scene segmentation' or 'shot boundary detection'. You should check the literature on that because there is no silver bullet solution. As many techniques applied in computer vision, segmentation highly depends on the content of the image/video and the features which can be extracted from it.

That said expressive features (e.g. extreme change in hue or brightness) can be easier detected than non expressive features (soccer game with a slight change). You will likely find some simple MATLAB code which can be converted into OpenCV code.

There are annotated datasets to test the yout algorithms.

Also take a look at: [What is the best way to divide a video into scenes (segments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317744/what-is-the-best-way-to-divide-a-video-into-scenes-segments)

Answer (score 2):

To do it programmatically, I would simply calculate the sum of absolute differences for the entire frame. This might, however, overflow quite easily, so possibly something like the average sum of absolute differences for two frames. You could then use some threshold value to determine if it's a key frame.

Using libraries like ffmpeg, you should be able to find the sum of absolute differences for macro-blocks as part of its motion estimation algorithms. As I'm not familiar with the library (I've only used the command-line tool), I cannot say whether it is possible to find the sums without generating motion vector, or if the sums will be available after. If it generates motion vectors, it might flag macro-blocks that have no nearby similar blocks.

Note that fast pans, dollys or zooms can easily be detected as cuts in this manner.

Cross-fades would not be detected unless they are sufficiently fast.

If higher accuracy is important, Paul's suggestion of using a simple clicker is a decent option.

You could write a program that tags all detected cuts, and allows for human control with simple key clicks (it could show the two frames involved, and the user can click y or n to tag it as correctly or incorrectly detected). If there are a lot of cuts, doing the control can take very long, but if the cuts are very fast, it might be hard for humans to detect or count correctly using a clicker anyway.